# How to return the logical value of a cell

Tags: excel

Lets say A1 is `=3>0`, of course it is `TRUE`. I want to make B1 based on if A1 is `TRUE`, but I dont want to use string comparison `=if(EXACT(A1, "TRUE"), "great", "sad")`. I want the first part of the if sentence to be judging if cell A1 is logically true. How can I do that? I need this because if I send this file to people using a different language, A1 might not be `TRUE`, but "true" in another language.

Comment: `=IF(A1, "great", "sad")`.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
=if(A1=TRUE(), "great", "sad")
```

TRUE() is a function so it should automatically change to local language while opening the file.

Update: user @BigBen posted in the comments even simpler solution:

```
=if(A1, "great", "sad")
```

as A1 already have logical value

Comment: thank you. =true() is better since I have other situations such as and(A1=false(), B2=false())...

Comment: @TingTing - you can use `NOT` for that situation.